# Is a good practice has a parameter for not check security issues when I have my app in debug?

Tags: android, ios, security

Recently I have to check some security issues in my Android and iOS apps. If app is running in an emulator, phone is rooted, is my app debuggable or debugger attached...

Checks for app debuggable and debugger attached don´t allow me to work correctly with my app when I'm developing, so I include a boolean parameter "isDebug" in my strings.xml file in Android. When compilation is debug is true, and when is release is false.

So I check this parameter in order to check security or not.

I don`t know if this is a good practice, or if I can do in other way. Can you put me in the correct way?

Comment: For Android why not use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` ? It is a public static final variable so that it is resolved completly at compile-time and code sections that are not reachable are just excluded at compile-time. Also the field is not accessed at run-time as the compiler has inlined all usages.

Comment: Ok, I will change that